# Limit the cart to a single product but without blocking the quantity

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I'm creating a course site where it is possible to register and pay via Woocomerce, I need to limit the possibility of adding multiple courses (products) to the cart but leave the possibility to select the quantity.  I found several indications on how not to allow the insertion of multiple products in the cart including the quantity but not as I want.  therefore you should be able to choose only one product but with the desired quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this code

````
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'add_to_cart_validation', 10, 1 );
function add_to_cart_validation( $passed ) {
    if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ){
        wc_add_notice( __(“Orders are limited to one item at a time”, "woocommerce" ), 'error' );
        $passed = false;
    }
    return $passed;
}```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).